# remove or skip null values in d3js stacked bar chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a data object to show stacked bars with an initial animation that plays upon loading the page, essentially where fruits correspond to orchards:

`[{Apple=1.0, Orange=2.0, Lettuce=1.0, orchard=小明, Blueberry=1.0}, {Apple=1.0, Orange=1.0, Lettuce=1.0, orchard=小陈, Blueberry=1.0}, {Apple=1.0, Orange=1.0, Lettuce=1.0, orchard=小虎, Blueberry=1.0}, {Orange=1.0, Lettuce=1.0, orchard=小桃, Blueberry=1.0, Apple=1.0}]`

The below code works fine if each orchard includes every fruit-type, but upon let's say removing Apples from everyone except for 小明, the y0 values for multiple orchards become 'NaN'. I am asking for a way to remove NaN values or find a way to skip them in d3js so that other fruits can still be displayed.

My rectangle code can be found below:

```
var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(0); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(0); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.x + ": " + d.y);
 });

  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .transition()
    .duration(800)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
    .delay(function(d,i){console.log(i) ; return(i*90)});
```

I am curious about using something like

```
   rect.filter(function(d) {
        return d.y == 0;
   })
   .remove();
```

But this does not seem to work. Unfortunately I am using d3js v3.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by reformatting how my d3 viz read keys. In my [answer to my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088270/avoid-enumerating-group-names-in-d3-layout-stackgroup-1-group-2) you can see how the keys variable was reformatted.

I don't have my v3 version saved on-file, but it had something to do with how stackedLayout works in v3. Not sure, but if you have a similar issue, I suggest reformatting how your variables are stacked to follow the same philosophy of using

```
  .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
```